Connecting branchline couplers
I have a conception on ADS to do about a Wilkinston divider and 3 branchline couplers.

The branchline coupler on ADS was asked to create it with a quadripole and configure his parameters S which I did:

But it gets more complicated when it comes to add the others couplers I don't know how to connect them. Can anyone help me please?

Hey Salima, your post seems to lack a concrete question, which makes it hard to answer. Could you please give some background where you are struggling and ask a concise question that you need answered?

What do you mean by 'and configure his' who is 'his'
